# How do i press only the "/" - key on a german keyboard?

Tags: android-studio, comments, shortcut, keyboard-layout

i searched for the shortcuts to comment a line in Android Studio.

The answer: Press the keys "Ctrl + /".

My problem: 
I tried this combination and ... nothing happened.

So now i assume that since i'm using a german keyboard and in this layout the "/" is mapped to the shift-option of the "7"-key it is not possible to press only the keys ctrl + /.

I tried to press ctrl + shift + 7 to enter "Ctrl + /", but this places a bookmark at that line which is named "7".

Does anyone know how to type in "Ctrl + /" while using a german layout (without changing the shortcut-mapping)?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is it not possible to change the shortcut in Android Studio?

Comment: I think so (up to now i have not searched for that)... but i would appreciate to know how to type in "Ctrl + /" on a complete default setup of Android Studio (if this is possible).
The reason is that i have to switch between many computers every day and i don't want to re-configure every one.
But nevertheless...thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: Switch to [EurKEY keyboard layout](https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu).

Comment: Thank you for this information, i will try this!

Answer (score 3):

I've found an answer for my question and i want to share it with you in case someone is struggeling with the same problem.

The answer is: 
If you're using a german keyboard with an integrated numpad you just need to press ctrl + "the numpad division key" to generate a "/".

In this way it is possible to type in "/" without pressing the shift-key.

Big thanks to all of you for your time and the warm welcome at stackoverflow!

Bye

Answer (score 1):

My laptop has a German keyboard and comes with an "FN" button which in a blue color, and if you press it combined with another button that has a blue color symbol such as
the number "0", which has the "/" in the blue color, it will type the "/" symbol.

To simplify, FN + 0 = "/". Therefore, CTRL + / can be achieved by combining CTRL + FN + 0, where FN + 0 = /.

Hope this helps you out. You need to find workarounds that suit your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

With the windows key + space bar you can change the Keyboard layout.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but i want to know if it is possible to type in "Ctrl + /" without switching the layout.... but nevertheless your comment helps me in other situations :)

Answer (score -1):

(In windows) You just press shift + /

In German keyboard shift means ↑.

Thanks.